# What's our stance on questions about other people's pets?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We have this question from a while back: "[How can I keep my neighbor's dogs out of my yard?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-can-i-keep-my-neighbors-dogs-out-of-my-yard)" Which I think is a pretty good question and likewise generated a pretty good discussion.

Now we have: "[How to get a roommate's dog to stop harassing girlfriends?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/how-to-get-roommates-dog-to-stop-harassing-girl-friends)" Which I think is okay. But the answer is really to discuss it with the roommate I think. Pretty much the same answer as the other one really.

Should we be accepting questions about interpersonal issues that involve pets? How many different answers can they really generate?

Answer (score 6):

Do we think we need a stance on this? I don't think we do. Each question, I think, can be answered or closed on the merit of the question and some will undoubtably be unanswerable, but not all of them. I don't know that a policy position is really needed at this time, we're not flooded by those questions and, well, we may get a real gem that can serve as canonical answer.

Life with a pet isn't always life with our own pet. :)